# No puedo hacer funcionar el bloque try y catch para una excepción no comprobada

Tags: java, excepciones, try-catch

```
package persona;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Persona {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner numero = new Scanner (System.in);
        String [] nombres = {"Santiago", "Macarena", "Leonardo", "Javier", "Santiago"};
        for(int i=0; i<100000; i++) {
            System.out.println("Inserte un número entre 0 y 4 incluyéndolos");
            System.out.println(nombres[numero.nextInt()]);
        }
        
        //try catch
        try {
            for(int i=0; i<100000; i++) {
                System.out.println("Inserte un número entre 0 y 4 incluyéndolos");
                System.out.println(nombres[numero.nextInt()]);
            }
            }
        catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            System.out.println("El número ingresado está fuera del alcance del array");
        }
    
    }

}
```

Cuando ejecuto el programa e ingreso un valor que está fuera del alcance del array me lanza el error del tipo que aparece dentro del catch(), pero no muestra el mensaje que está dentro del bloque catch. No sé si es porque no se ejecuta directamente el try catch o si hay algún error de otro tipo.

Comment: Tienes el bucle duplicado, nunca llegas a ejecutar el código del try catch porque tendrías que meter 100000 números previamente

Comment: @PabloLozano gracias, pero yo necesito que se ejecute cuando por teclado ingreso un número que está fuera del alcance del array como se ve en la captura (ejemplo ingreso un 5). No sé si esto se soluciona quitando el bucle del try o cómo? si me pudieras explicar te agradezco muchas gracias

Comment: Tienes dos bucles for idénticos: elimina el que está fuera del bloque try-catch

Comment: @PabloLozano muchísimas gracias crack ahí solucioné

Answer (score 0):

Se esta produciendo un error del tipo

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

aunque usas manejo de exceptions para capturar este tipo de error, el error sucede en el primer `for` que no tiene el manejo de exeptions, por cierto no necesitas los dos `for` ya que realizan el mismo proceso

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner numero = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] nombres = {"Santiago", "Macarena", "Leonardo", "Javier", "Santiago"};

    try {            
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
            System.out.println("Inserte un número entre 0 y 4 incluyéndolos");
            System.out.println(nombres[numero.nextInt()]);
        }
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        System.out.println("El número ingresado está fuera del alcance del array");
    }
  
}
```